# readがうまくできない。

Tags: c

上手くreadできません。

text.txt

```
ABC
```

main.c

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int sz, fd = open("text.txt", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);
    char *c = (char *)calloc(100 , sizeof(char));
    
    printf("%d\n", fd);
    sz = read(fd, c, 100);
    printf("called read(% d, c, sz).  returned that"
         " %d bytes  were read.\n", fd, sz);
    printf("%s", c);
    return 0 ;
}
```

これの出力が以下です

```
3
called read( 3, c, sz).  returned that 12 bytes  were read.
 ■A
```

まず、ABC しか書かれてないのに 12byte 読んでるのは変だし、"ABC" と表示されないのもおかしいです。

これは Windows を使っているせいでしょうか？なお、コンパイラは mingw です。
Linux で実行した場合は正常に動作しました。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows上の`text.txt`ファイルが、BOMおよび改行コード付きのUTF-16LEエンコーディングであれば、それは正しい動作です。

該当ファイルをマウス右クリック等でプロパティを確認すれば、サイズが12バイトになっているでしょう。

そのファイルを16進数でダンプ表示すると、以下のようになるはずです。

```
FF,FE,41,00,42,00,43,00,0D,00,0A,00,
```

Windows上のC言語での`char`は8bitで、printfの%sは0x00で終端されるcharの配列であるモードで使われていたのでしょう。
ファイル読み取りのサイズはバイト単位で通知されます。

そのため、読み取ったサイズは12バイトだし、`printf("%s", c);`では`FF,FE,41`までが出力対象で、 `■A`のように表示されます。(ちなみにVC++のコンソールアプリで(動くように修正して)やってみたら、`A`と表示された(Aの前は実際には中点`・`のように見えました)ので`FF,FE`の表示に関しては環境依存の可能性が大きいかもしれません)

---

Linux上で上手くいったのは、Linux上で使用した`text.txt`ファイルがWindows上の物とは違っていた(ASCII/ShiftJIS/UTF-8BOM無しで、改行コード無し)のだと思われます。

Comment: ご指摘の通り、改行ありのENCODING：UTF-16 LE　になっていました。

Comment: UTF-8で実行したら、linux環境下と同じ出力になりました！ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 5):

原因はおそらく @kunif さんの回答であっていそうですが、提示プログラムはいくつか問題を抱えていますので指摘だけ

https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man2/open.2.html

1. `open()` に `O_CREAT` を指定する場合は第３引数として `mode` を指定しなければなりません。
2. `open()` で `O_RDONLY` と `O_CREAT` を同時に指定するのはたぶん誤りです。こうすると

- 指定ファイルが既に存在するとき `O_CREAT` は無視される（こっちはおそらく期待通り）
- 指定ファイルが無いとき `O_CREAT` により 0 バイト長の新規ファイルが作られる（こっちは多分期待通りでない）
  0 バイト長なので直ちに EOF となる
- 作られた新規ファイルの権限が不定値 (1. により)

---

[cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) / [mingw](/questions/tagged/mingw) の場合、ファイル内容のダンププログラムが付属しているので、これでバイト内容を確認するとよいでしょう。

```
$ od -tx1 text.txt
0000000 ff fe 41 00 42 00 43 00 0d 00 0a 00
0000014
$
```

であれば BOM あり UTF-16LE 改行ありですし

```
$ od -tx1 text.txt
0000000 41 42 43
0000003
$
```

であれば ASCII (UTF-8) 改行なしです。